# Drop down selection changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down that is supposed to change features on my page but obviously isnt working.  I have a map on on the drop down selection once the user selects and industry it updates the map and is supposed to update the legend below.  The legend is not updating

Please point out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

**JS**

```
    $("#lstMap1Occ").change(function () {
        var index = $(this).children(":selected").index();
        $("#legend").children().hide().eq(index).show();
    });
```

here is the drop down (yes there is an  ending select tag is ist just not pasting in for some odd reason)

```
<select id="lstMap1Occ">
    <option value="1">Engineers </option>
    <option value="2">Chemical Engineers</option>
</select>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="legend">
<div class="engineers">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(254,240,217);">0-345</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(253,212,158);">346-503</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(253,187,132);">504-1240</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(252,141,89);">1241-1679</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(239,101,72);">1680-2625</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(215,48,31);">2627-4789</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="chemical"> 
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(254,240,217);">0-13</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(253,212,158);">14-24</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(253,187,132);">25-37</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(252,141,89);">38-56</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(239,101,72);">57-112</li>
        <li style="background-color:rgb(215,48,31);">113-168</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First problem is $("#legend") should be $(".legend"), but that's not the entirety of it.

Comment: Is there a closing for your legend, as well?

Comment: actually i had been looking at this for so long that I never did change the "#" to a "."  Once I did that it worked and I intended.  Thanks for point it out Nathan

Comment: glad to have helped, it's so easy to overlook.

Comment: @NathanKoop - post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.legend not #legend    http://jsfiddle.net/fy6hf/1/

```
$("#lstMap1Occ").change(function () {
        var index = $(this).children(":selected").index();
        $(".legend").children().hide().eq(index).show();
    });
```